# unknown attribute 'category_id' for Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create categories for my posts. To do so, I generated a new category model. Although I have associated the two models, I am still receiving this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'category_id' for Post.
```

I have doublechecked the schema which does include category_id for the post table:

add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "cost"
    t.integer  "openspots"
    t.boolean  "approval"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
```

Here are my associations as well:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments

  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Finally I wanted to include my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # @post = Post.new
    @post = Post.new
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :cost, :openspots, :approval, :category_id))
    @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
    @post.user = current_user
     if @post.save
       flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
       redirect_to @post
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
     if @post.update_attributes(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description))
       flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
       redirect_to @post
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Whenever I create a new post, the post is created successfully;however, the category id is never saved.

Here is my view as well:

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>Guidelines for posts</p>
     <ul>
       <li>Make sure it rhymes.</li>
       <li>Don't use the letter "A".</li>
       <li>The incessant use of hashtags will get you banned.</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :title %>
         <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :description %>
         <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post description" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :cost %>
         <%= f.number_field :cost, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter cost" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :openspots %>
         <%= f.number_field  :openspots, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Number of Open Spots" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :approval %>
         <%= f.check_box  :approval, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Check if Approval Necessary" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :category %>
         <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is it not working in development or production?

Comment: This is not working in development. The weird thing I noticed is that if I define a category id within the console, it will display. But the category id is not saved when I am creating a post within my form

Comment: can you post the relevant views, like when you submit the form to create a post

Comment: Most of the time these errors come from people forgetting to run rake db:migrate, but in this case it's already in your schema and your associations/controller seem correct aswell so it must be something in your views.

Comment: You say the category_id is not saved when created from the form.  Are you sure that it's in the params hash?  Put a breakpoint in the create action of the controller and see what the params are.

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError means that you're missing a field in the database or you forgot to run your migrations.Just re-check if both of the things is been done correctly.